# Does KEY/KEYREF work with JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I have an XSD file declaring lots of classes (using unmarshalling). Upto now, there was one relationship between two of the generated classes, which is modelled by using ID and IDREF. This works perfectly well.
I have to change the app. Now I have two independent relationships and ID/IDREF doesn't work anymore.
I guess, I have to use xs:key/xs:keyref.
But, all I found on JAXB2 suggests, that unmarshalling of xs:key/xs:keyref just validates, but doesn't generate the relationship in Java code.
Is this still true?
Regards, Claus